# Modifying bst file - changing separator

Tags: bibtex

I am currently modifying a bst file. The problem I am facing now is how to change the separator of the style.

At the moment, I get the following output:

> Badie, Dina (2010) ‘Groupthink, iraq, and the war on terror: Explaining us policy shifts toward iraq’ Foreign Policy Analysis 6(4):277–296.

However, I need the following output:

> Badie, Dina (2010) ‘Groupthink, iraq, and the war on terror: Explaining us policy shifts toward iraq’, Foreign Policy Analysis 6(4):277–296.

With NO comma after the year, but WITH a comma after the title (and after the editor in a chapter of an edited volume).

Here is the code of the bst file:

```
FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
        %{ add.period$ write$
        { " " * write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { add.period$ " " * write$ }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}

FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title quote "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    {
      journal
      "journal" bibinfo.check

      "journal" output.check
      add.blank
      format.vol.num.pages output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { "t" change.case$ }
  if$
  "title" bibinfo.check
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you've included enough information to address the problem.  If the bibliographic entry is of type `@ARTICLE`, then you should start by showing us the `FUNCTION {article}` entry.  More may still be needed, if the function shunts to a sub-function to handle the title and the date.

Comment: Looking at the `article` function you provide, it would seem that any punctuation following the year would be handled by the function `format.date` or maybe `date.block`.  Likewise, punctuation following the title would likely be handled in `format.date` or `new.block`.  In the four functions I just mentioned, you might look to see in which ones a comma appears, as that is probably the origin of the comma in your output.  (Also note that in your example, there is no discrepancy after the year in how the "bad" and "good" references are shown)

Comment: I do not need a comma after the year, but after the title! that is my problem

Comment: One indispensible reference for working with BibTeX is http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf

Comment: It is possible that, in the `article` function, changing the line `format.title quote "title" output.check` to something like `format.title quote "," * "title" output.check` might give you the needed comma.  The insertion of `"," *` says to concatenate a comma to the prior string.  But whether that will work depends on what `format.title` is really doing.

Comment: I have added the format.title function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to solve the problem on my own. So I modified the @article function by changing

```
format.title quote "title" output.check
```

to

```
format.title ", " * quote "title" output.check
```

Here is the complete function

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title ", " * quote "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    {
      journal
      "journal" bibinfo.check
      emphasize
      "journal" output.check
      add.blank
      format.vol.num.pages output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
```

The result looks like this:

> Burke, John P. (2005a) ‘Condoleezza Rice as NSC Advisor: A Case of the Honest Broker Role, ’ Presidential Studies Quarterly 35(3): 554–575.

However, I want the comma to be outside the quote, as follows:

> Burke, John P. (2005a) ‘Condoleezza Rice as NSC Advisor: A Case of the Honest Broker Role’, Presidential Studies Quarterly 35(3): 554–575.

How can I solve that Problem? Maybe by changing the quote function?

```
FUNCTION {quote}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "`" swap$ * "'" * }
  if$
}
```

Comment: What happens when you place the `quote` command before the `", "`, rather than after the `*`?

Comment: Excellent.  The switch allowed the `quote` to apply first, prior to the concatenation of the comma.